# Question in "Linked" sidebar is not referenced anywhere in this question or its answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, linked-questions

I'm referring to this question:  [what is the right way to treat Python argparse.Namespace() as a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878315/what-is-the-right-way-to-treat-python-argparse-namespace-as-a-dictionary).

On the sidebar of that question, it lists two other questions, one of which is related and the other is completely unrelated ([Is There Any Way To Check if a Twitch Stream Is Live Using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064130/is-there-any-way-to-check-if-a-twitch-stream-is-live-using-python?lq=1)).  I was curious, so I searched the page source for any possible references to that question, and I could find none.

I've seen this before on other questions.  Why would SO mistakenly list bugs as linked that are not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "linked" section of the sidebar is not a one-way street for only questions linked in the question you are viewing. If the question you are viewing has been linked on *another* question somewhere on the site, then that question will also appear in the list as linked.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the first comment for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23621562/4342498) there is a link to the main post.  this is the reason it is showing up in the linked sidebar.